# Keep selection on Tkinter Entry widget despite not having focus

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, focus, tkinter-entry

When a user selects a portion of text in a Tkinter Entry widget it becomes highlighted. However, when the user clicks away from the widget the highlighting disappears.

Is there any way to keep the selected text highlighted despite the `Entry` widget not having focus?

I'm attempting to make a custom right-click menu not based on the Tkinter Menu widget (it's based on a Tkinter Toplevel widget), and I would like the text to remain highlighted despite the menu having focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set the `exportselection` option of the text widget to `False`

```
text_widget.configure(exportselection=False)
```